# How to store variables in github pages

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages

So I have a website with html and javascript where I need to keep a simple variable state, lets say is just a counter. Is there any way to use github pages and their access to secrets/issues/pr to store this variable so I don't have to set up a backed server?

The variable would be just a number between 1 and 20.

Thanks,

Comment: is the variable supposed to be dynamic? you can just host an empty page with the number no?

Comment: I don't think you can. What about storing the value client side with localStorage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't store the variables because Github Pages is a frontend only provider.
But you might want to look at [github secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets), I'm not sure if you are able to change them on runtime, but you could give it a try.

Also if you want the variable to be stored for 1 user at a time, you can use browser local storage or cookies.